# What would be the proper implementation of a concept describing a raw pointer (to objects)?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++-concepts, raw-pointer

This might be of academic interest only.

Because I noticed that my practical example might not be the suitable one to raise that question.

Originally I had written something like

```
auto bak_ptr{ptr}; // think of an `int* ptr`
```

to make a backup of an address.
Now I wondered if I could do better by replacing that dumb `auto` by a more meaningful, horizon broadening C++20 concept.

After some thought, the right choice in that specific example might just be

```
std::copyable auto bak_ptr{ptr};
```

because that's mirroring the intent of a backup, a copy of something.

But the academic question remaining is: What would be a proper (concepts standard library) implementation correctly mapping the behavior of the raw pointer concept? And let's restrict 'pointer' to pointer to objects for know, if necessary. There are also pointers to void, functions, members - perhaps complicating the issue.

I thought of a relationship to iterators. Hopefully not yet again answering my own question correctly: would `std::contiguous_iterator` be a valuable choice in cases?
Could someone please share a more or less complete expert view on that topic?

And why there might be no std::pointer_to_object standard library implementation for that concept yet (yelling the thing into your face)?

Comment: `ptr` is an `int*` ?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with asking questions of academic interest :) I think you're looking for exactly [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_pointer).

Comment: In this specific case, why not `auto *`?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "pointer to object"? The only pointer I can think which is a "pointer to object" is a pointer to a primitive like a pointer to an int; which is what you use as example.

Comment: @al3c "There are also pointers to void, functions, members - perhaps complicating the issue." -- all of these are indeed not objects.

Comment: Of course, in the example it's a very different question, whether you would want to write anything else than `auto` ever at all. Perhaps not.

Comment: @cigien `std::is_pointer`, might be so simple, yes. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Think about how you would use it, and if you figure it out, go ahead and post an answer :)

Comment: @al3c `std::string*` is a pointer-to-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just building up upon `std::is_pointer` there should be nothing wrong with

```
template <class T>
concept pointer =
  std::is_pointer_v<T>;
```

Thanks to [@cigien](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8372853/cigien) for that idea.

And I would say that in the simple backup example the choice of `std::copyable` instead is exactly right. As that's what you want to do with the backup, restore it again by copy.

Answer (score 1):

To signal that `bak_ptr` is a raw pointer-to-object does not require any fancy shenanigans:

```
auto* bak_ptr{ptr};
```

Comment: Valid! I also tried to learn something about using concepts. The way you think about what to do with types. So even the `pointer auto bak_ptr{ptr};` answer might not be fully complete. As in the backup example I'm not even sure yet whether 'pointer' is the right word there. Of course in practice in that simple example `auto`/`auto*` are the only sound choices.

Comment: Honestly... just write `int* copyOfPtr = ptr;` Clear what it means, clear what it does, clear what it's for, and no "clever" complications that actually just make everything ten times harder to understand. Then you move on to the next "problem".